# Read JSON files from Folder and Store it into a CSV file

Tags: python, export-to-csv, json2csv

I have around 1000 JSON files in a folder, I want to convert all those files to its CSV formats. The sample of JSON file is given below.

```
{"Reviews": 
   [
    {"Title": "Don't give up on your NOOK HD just yet - make it a Lean Mean Jellybean with OS 4.2.2", 
    "Author": "DC10", 
    "ReviewID": "ROX6OFU4UAOK1", 
    "Overall": "5.0", 
    "Content": "Hi Folks, ", 
    "Date": "February 18, 2013"}, 

    {"Title": "freezing problem",
    "Author": "joseph",
    "ReviewID": "R1QVAPUULQZ57B",
    "Overall": "3.0", 
    "Content": "I am still setting it up the way I want it I havve downloaded anything to it yet and it freezes horribly. All in all tho I love this device.", 
    "Date": "September 11, 2013"}
    ], 
"ProductInfo": {"Price": "$229.00", "Features": "NOOK HD 7\" 16GB Tablet", "Name": "NOOK HD 7\" 16GB Tablet", 
"ImgURL": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41jpVvVz41L._SY300_.jpg", 
"ProductID": "1400501520"}}
```

Comment: Could you provide the expected structure of the .csv file? Also, properly formatting your answer would help a lot.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

example: json to csv

imports:

```
import json
import csv
```

some json :D

```
data_json = {
    "employee_details": [{
            "nom": "Bobby",
            "age": "19",
        }]
}
```

and some code

```
employee_data = data_json['employee_details']

# open a file for writing
employ_data = open('EmployData.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(employ_data)

count = 0
for employee in employee_data:
      if count == 0:
             header = employee.keys()
             csvwriter.writerow(header)
             count += 1
      csvwriter.writerow(employee.values())

employ_data.close()
```

you will find the file EmployeeData.csv next to your script

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to install a 3rd party module, you can do this in a few lines with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
for json_file in files:
    with open(json_file) as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)

    df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(json_data)
    df.to_csv(json_file.rstrip('.json') + '.csv')
```